# Which font family is Google Charts using?

Tags: fonts, google-visualization

I tried a lot to format a legend in the Google Chart API, and have almost done it, but still need an extra data that I cannot find. I know that I cannot change the font family Google uses to draw the legend, but if I knew which font is using i'll be able do success.

So, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in a [piechart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html) you can overwrite the default font (which is Arial) with the [`fontName`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html#Configuration_Options) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? do you have any example page? in the quick start you can clearly see that the legend is Arial

http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html

```
<text x="263" y="91" 
    font-family="Arial" 
    font-size="11" 
    stroke="none" 
    stroke-width="0" 
    fill-opacity="1" 
    stroke-opacity="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="0" 
    fill="#222222">
Olives
</text>
```